# What is the layer of grey stuff on the bottom of salmon?

Tags: fish, salmon

On the bottom of a piece of salmon there is a layer of grey stuff, I am wondering what this is?  I assume this is its fat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is coagulated albumin leaked from the flesh of the fish.  Not terribly inviting, but not harmful either.